# Adding a JPanel into a JFrame

Tags: swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I know this sounds like an easy question, but I am making a simple text adventure with buttons and such, and I cant figure out how to add my Jpanel into my JFrame. My JPanel has a bunch of buttons and graphics and stuff if that makes a difference. I have provided the code below. frame panel=new frame(); is the other class which extends JPanel. I know its confusing that its called "frame", its because I used to have it extend JFrame. Anyways my code doesnt produce the buttons, graphics etc, from the other class like it should. Thanks,

```
package sonomaroller;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.*;

public class SonomaRoller extends JFrame {

    public static Dimension size = new Dimension(550,550); //Dimension of Frame
    public static String title = "Sonoma Roller v0.00" ;


    public SonomaRoller(){

      setTitle(title);
        setSize(size);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null); // null centers window on screen
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        System.out.println("hello?");  
        //setLayout(null); 
        setVisible(true);

    }


   public static void main(String[] args) {

       SonomaRoller object1=new SonomaRoller();   
       frame panel=new frame();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SonomaRoller object1=new SonomaRoller();   
frame panel=new frame();
object1.getContentPane().add(panel);
```

or just simply

```
object1.add(panel);
```

From: [JFrame#getContentPane()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#getContentPane%28%29)
and [Container#add(Component)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29)

Here's some code that works if it helps:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    public MyFrame() {
        add(new MyPanel());
        setSize(640, 480);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                new MyFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    @Override protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillOval(20, 20, 80, 80);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for your other class? Also, make sure you're not setting the layout managers to null. Prefer using [these](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) layout managers and setting the preferred size of your components instead.

Comment: I have uploaded my code from other classes. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this...?

```
package sonomaroller;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame.*;

public class SonomaRoller extends JFrame {

    public static Dimension size = new Dimension(550,550); //Dimension of Frame
    public static String title = "Sonoma Roller v0.00" ;


    public SonomaRoller(){

      setTitle(title);
        setSize(size);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null); // null centers window on screen
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        System.out.println("hello?");  
        //setLayout(null); 
        setVisible(true);

        frame panel=new frame();
        setContentPane(panel);
    }


   public static void main(String[] args) {

       SonomaRoller object1=new SonomaRoller();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I normally do it:

```
public class SonomaRoller extends JFrame {

    public SonomaRoller(){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        JPanel newPanel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(newPanel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the problem :

```
frame panel=new frame();
```

put this line instead of above code :

```
Frame frame = new Frame();
Panel panel = new Panel();
frame.add(panel);
```